# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x176b)

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

When I try to make a simple app, I get this error:

```
@IBAction func pickButton(sender: UIButton) {
    numberLabel.text = String(format: "The number is %@", randomNumber) Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x176b)
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickButton: UIButton!
    var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10000) + 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func pickButton(sender: UIButton) {
        numberLabel.text = String(format: "The number is %@", randomNumber)
    }
}
```

Please help, I don't know what I should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%@` format is for printing Foundation objects such as `NSString`,
`NSNumber` etc.

```
var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10000) + 1
```

is a `UInt32` and that is printed with `%u` for "unsigned integer":

```
numberLabel.text = String(format: "The number is %u", randomNumber)
```

Alternatively, use `%@` and convert the integer to `NSNumber`:

```
numberLabel.text = String(format: "The number is %@", NSNumber(unsignedInt: randomNumber))
```

But in your case the easiest solution is to use *string interpolation*:

```
numberLabel.text = "The number is \(randomNumber)"
```

Answer (score 2):

`randomNumber` in an integer, not an object. The format specifier `%@` expects an object. Use an appropriate format specifier such as `%u`.

See [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for documentation.